# JsPlumb connector line points otside the screen when tree is collapsed

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I am using jQuery to implement 2 expandable trees placed side by side and i am using jsplumb to connect the elements between two with a connector line. After Connecting the elements if i collapse the tree the connector starts pointing outside the screen

Comment: I am looking for a solution where after collapsing the connector should point to the parent element

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Note that you can edit your own question to make clear what solution you are looking for.